# How do I use my phone as a GSM gateway in asterisk the OpenERP module?

Tags: bluetooth, odoo, asterisk, voip, gsm

I have done my search and this led to :

chan_mobile is an addon to asterisk the app that helps you use your phone a GSM-VoIP gateway.

chan-dongle is as chan_mobile but allows you to use your phone with bluetooth.

These addons are not available for the openerp addon (or module) asterisk. Is there a way to link openerp module asterisk with the app asterisk ( like an xml-rpc ) or is there any other way to use my phone as a gsm gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Assuming that you are using ubuntu os install bluetooth drivers first
    apt-get install bluez-utils bluez-hcidump libbluetooth-dev

Then install chan_mobile module to you asterisk, for that go to /usr/src/asterisk-version

```
./configure && make menuselect
```

Select chan_moblie from applications and

```
make && make install
```

Once done pair your phone to asterisk server. for that make your phone discoverable and scan

```
hcitool scan
Scanning ...
       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX    Myphone
```

Make a note of the MAC address. In order to pair, a helper is required to handle the PIN. Run the helper in the background and begin the pairing process:

```
bluetooth-agent 1234 &
rfcomm connect hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Once the pairing has succeeded, make sure your phone is configured to automatically accept connections for this paring in future. You can verify that the paring is working at any time by running:

```
hcitool con
Connections:
    < ACL XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX handle 41 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

Now load asterisk and load module chan_moblie

```
asterisk -rvvvvvv
module load chan_mobile.so
```

Search for mobile

```
mobile search 
    XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Myphone                     Yes    Phone   2
```

In this case it is rfcomm channel 2. In addition, we need to know the MAC address of the bluetooth dongle installed in the Asterisk server. Exit the Asterisk CLI and use hcitool:

```
hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    YY:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Edit the chan_mobile configuration file:
    nano /etc/asterisk/chan_mobile.conf
    [Adapter]
    address = YY:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    id = asteriskpbx

```
[Myphone]
address = XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
port = 2
context = from-MySipphone
adapter = asteriskpbx
```

Add dial plan

```
nano /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf
[from-MySipphone]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/100)

[my-phones]
exten => *12,1,Dial(MOBILE/Myphone/150)
```

And you are done......:)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't allow me to use the phone from the OpenERP interface, only from the asterisk one.